# Heteroskedasticity assumption in fGLS into linear form?

Tags: econometrics, heteroskedasticity

I am following Chapter 8 ("Heteroskedasticity" p. 259) in the 6th edition of Woolridge *Introductory Econometrics: A Modern Approach* and I don't understand one piece of the transformation of our model.

For fGLS, we assume [1] $Var(u|\boldsymbol{x}) = \sigma^2exp(\delta_0 +\delta_1x_1+\delta_2x_2+...+\delta_kx_k)$, where $x_i, x_2,...,x_k$ are the independent variables appearing in the regression model and the $\delta_j$ are unknown parameters.

Then, we use the definition of conditional variance to say $Var(u|\boldsymbol{x}) = E(u^2|\boldsymbol{x}$), since our zero conditional mean assumption tells us that $(E(u))^2$ is zero.

**Now, here is where I'm stuck**: Wooldridge says that our assumption [1] above allows us to write $u^2=\sigma^2exp(\delta_0 +\delta_1x_1+\delta_2x_2+...+\delta_kx_k)v$, where $v$ has a mean equal to unity, conditional on $\boldsymbol{x}=x_1,x_2, ...,x_k$

Can someone please help me to develop an intuition for this last step that Wooldridge has taken?  Essentially, it seems like we've assumed that $E(u^2|\boldsymbol{x})=\frac{u^2}{v}$ and I don't understand why or the properties that allow us to do this.

I've found this paper https://www.econ.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:e3cddc1b-f89d-4fb4-9474-c2c380355d69/joe_2017.pdf to be useful (specifically, assumption #6 on p. 2), but it doesn't leave me with much intuition for what we're doing and why, especially because I'm fairly new to econometrics.

Thanks-
Maurus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the 4th edition, but the content should be the same.  It sounds like you are asking how he got from

$$
Var(u|\boldsymbol{x}) = \sigma^2exp(\delta_0 +\delta_1x_1+\delta_2x_2+...+\delta_kx_k)
$$

to

$$
u^2=\sigma^2exp(\delta_0 +\delta_1x_1+\delta_2x_2+...+\delta_kx_k)v
$$

As you correctly noted, $Var(u|\boldsymbol{x}) = E(u^2|\boldsymbol{x})$ under the zero conditional mean expectation assumption ($E(u|\boldsymbol{x}) = 0$).  So that allows us to replace the left-hand side of the equation, as Wooldridge did.  $E(u^2|\boldsymbol{x})$ turned into $u^2$ because $u^2 = E(u^2|\boldsymbol{x}) + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is the component of $u^2$ that's uncorrelated with any function of $\boldsymbol{x}$.  That component could have been left in at this stage, but it can be removed because later on it would turn into a part of the error term anyway that does not affect the fitted values from the regression of $log(u^2)$ on $\boldsymbol{x}$ (i.e., part of $e$ in the next equation in the book).

On the right-hand side of the equation, Wooldridge adds $v$, which has a mean equal to unity, conditional on $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_k)$.  That means that given some set of values for $\boldsymbol{x}$, $v$ is expected to have a multiplicative factor effect of $1$ on $u^2$ (in other words, no effect).  By introducing this term to the equation (and assuming that it is independent of $\boldsymbol{x}$), we can then convert it into the error term $e$ in the subsequent equation:

$$
log(u^2) = \alpha_0 + \delta_1x_1+\delta_2x_2+...+\delta_kx_k+e
$$

because taking a log of a variable that has a mean of $1$ will give us a variable that has a mean of $0$ plus some constant (equal to the negative of the mean of the log values of the original variable $v$).  That constant is moved to the constant term (that's why this last equation has $\alpha_0$ instead of $\delta_0$) and we are left with an equation that can be estimated using OLS.

P.S. The $v$ in this book is not the same $v$ that you found in Assumption 6 in the linked paper.  There it is a function, not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Let us write $\mathbf{x}\delta = \delta_0 + \delta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \delta_k x_k$ for notational brevity. If $u^2 = \sigma^2 \exp(\mathbf{x}\delta) v$, where $E(v|\mathbf{x})=1$, then it is indeed true that
$$E(u^2|\mathbf{x}) = \sigma^2 \exp(\mathbf{x}\delta) E(v|\mathbf{x}) = \sigma^2 \exp(\mathbf{x}\delta).$$
The LHS is $Var(u|\mathbf{x})$ by definition when $E(u|\mathbf{x})=0$ as you noted.

Note that $u^2 = \sigma^2 \exp(\mathbf{x}\delta) v$ is not the only possible path to $E(u^2|\mathbf{x}) = \sigma^2 \exp(\mathbf{x}\delta)$. Another possibility is $u^2 = \sigma^2 \exp(\mathbf{x}\delta) + v$ with $E(v|\mathbf{x})=0$, which also implies $E(u^2|\mathbf{x}) = \sigma^2 \exp(\mathbf{x}\delta)$. Wooldridge chooses the multiplicative model $u^2 = \sigma^2 \exp(\mathbf{x}\delta) v$ with $E(v|\mathbf{x})=1$ because he wants to take log (note $v>0$ is also needed) and have a linear model. AlexK gives a nice explanation on the derivation of the linear model.

Wait. Why is taking log so important? It's because we want the fitted values to be *strictly positive* (by applying its inverse function, exp) for all $i$. It is also so nice that a linear model is derived, which is extremely easy to estimate. A model like $u^2 = \exp(\mathbf{x}\delta) + \varepsilon$ or $u^2 = (\mathbf{x}\delta)^2 +\varepsilon$ with $E(\varepsilon|\mathbf{x})=0$ also give strictly positive fitted values but it's not a linear model so estimation is hard.

To add a bit more technical details. We need that $v$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are mutually *independent* so that $\log(v)$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are mutually independent. Then after taking log, we have
$$\log (u^2) = \log(\sigma^2) + \mathbf{x} \delta + \log(v),$$
where $E[\log(v)|\mathbf{x}] = E[\log(v)]$ is a (nonzero) constant independent of $\mathbf{x}$, and we have a standard linear model after adjusting the intercept. Actually, we don't even need $E(v|\mathbf{x})=1$. All we need is that $v$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are mutually independent.

Comment: A good supplement to support the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\sigma^2 = 1$. If $E[u^2|x] = f(x)$ for some $f(x) > 0$ , then, trivially,
$$
u^2 = f(x) \frac{u^2}{f(x)},
$$
where $v = \frac{u^2}{f(x)}$ has mean equal to 1. In this particular case, $f(x) = exp(\cdots)$.